# cppman analog for C?

Tags: c++, c, manpage

I'm new with **C**, so I'd like to use some manual pages directly from console.

Under **Linux** I can use `cppman`, to get tips about varios functions in **C++**, for example:

```
$ cppman printf | head -n 10
printf(3)                                                                                  C++ Programmer's Manual                                                                                  printf(3)



NAME
       printf - Print formatted data to stdout

TYPE
       function
```

Is there something lie this tool, but specially for **C**?

Because - there is some differents, for example:

```
$ cppman printf | grep -A 4 SYNOPSIS
SYNOPSIS
       #include <cstdio>

       int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

UPD

Looking in `man` doesn't give results:

```
$ man 3 printf
No entry for printf in section 3 of the manual

$ man -k printf
...
printf               (1)  - format and print data
printf [builtins]    (1)  - bash built-in commands, see bash(1)
...
```

And also - `printf` here is just example, but whet about more complicated items?
For example:

```
$ man bool
No manual entry for bool

$ cppman bool | grep -A 8 EXAMPLE
EXAMPLE
         // modify boolalpha flag
         #include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::boolalpha, std::noboolalpha
         int main () {
           bool b = true;
           std::cout << std::boolalpha << b << '0;
           std::cout << std::noboolalpha << b << '0;
           return 0;
         }
```

Comment: What's wrong with `man printf`?

Comment: @GregHewgill it'll show the manpage for `printf(1)`, i.e. the shell command.

Comment: Well sure, `man 3 printf` to get the libc version. In the absence of a conflicting shell built-in, `man` works as expected.

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks, I edited Q and add some more description :-)

Comment: @setevoy If `man 3 printf` isn't returning results, you most likely don't have the libc manpages installed.

Comment: @Sneftel yep... seems default `man` doesn't include all of them :-) Could you add this comment to your answer? P.S. But - even now, there is nothing about `bool`... >> cppman generates C++ manual pages from cplusplus.com and provide a man-like interface to view man pages

Comment: @setevoy sho' thing. As for the lack of `bool`, that's probably because it isn't in C.

Comment: @Sneftel Ah! I found it. Need to search by header file name :-)
`$ man stdbool.h`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular old `man` will work. You can pass the `-S3` option (or just `3`) to restrict results to C standard library functions. If you don't see C standard library functions in your man results, you need to install the libc manpage collection.